# jQuery Validation - Doing Depends in Bulk?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Ok, this might be a stupid question, but is there a way to determine what groups (not form groups) of fields are required based on some external values - without doing a (bloated/redundant) depends on the rules for EVERY field?

Lets say I have a form that has checkboxes to indicate what vehicles a person has (car, motorcycle, boat). If they check the car box, the car fields (make, model, year, etc) are shown. If the motorcycle box is checked, then the motorcyle fields are shown (make, model, engine, etc). And so on..

So, based on which of those 3 checkboxes are check, I want to validate the appropriate fields. How can I do this w/o putting a depends on each field/rule?

Can the rules for each of the vehicle types be stored in 3 preset arrays and then be added/removed based on the checkbox selections? Something like this VERY simplified version:

```
var car_rules_array = {
  car_make: {
    required:true
  },
  car_model: {
    required:true
  },
  car_year: {
    required:true

  },
  car_purchased: {
    required: true,
    date: true
  },
  car_vin: {
    required: true,
    remote: {
     url: blah..
    } 
  }
}


var boat_rules_array = {
  boat_make: {
    required:true
  },
  boat_model: {
    required:true
  },
  boat_year: {
    required:true

  },
  boat_purchased: {
    required: true,
    date: true
  },
  boat_sn: {
    required: true,
    remote: {
     url: blah..
    } 
  }
}


if ($('#has_car').is(':checked') == true) {

  $('#TheForm').addrules(car_rules_array);

} else {

  $('#TheForm').removerules(car_rules_array);

}
```

?

I'm just not getting it.

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to show a sample code example including the relevant HTML.

Comment: Otherwise, did you look at the docs?  `.rules('add')` and `.rules('remove')` for dynamically controlling rules without needing a `depends` property.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/

Comment: Ok, I see how I can iterate the arrays/objects and add the rules to each of the fields, but...I guess what Im asking is if there is a way to push/pop the arrays directly to the $("#TheFormr").validate() function rules object.

Comment: No, you cannot dynamically change rules using the `.validate()` method.  Once `.validate()` is called, the plugin is initialized on your form and you cannot call it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.rules('add')` and `.rules('remove')` for dynamically controlling rules without the `depends` property.

```
if ($('#has_car').is(':checked') == true) {

    // use .rules('add')

    $('#fieldID').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        // another rule,...
    });

} else {

    // use .rules('remove')

    $('#fieldID').rules('remove', 'required');

}
```

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/

---

**EDIT:**

Response based on edited OP.

No, you cannot dynamically change rules using the `.validate()` method. Once `.validate()` is called, the plugin is initialized on your form and you cannot call it again... it's just ignored.  This is why the developer gives you the `.rules()` method.

Since `.rules()` is attached to a field and `.validate()` is attached to the form, you cannot interchange their object literals.  The former is simply a list of rules (for a field) and the latter is a list of all field names and their rules.

The only thing I can suggest that may make it a little more efficient would be to put a common class on each set of fields.  Like `car` and `boat`.  Then you can target multiple fields at once using an `.each()`.  Not perfect, but you get the idea and can probably get creative...

```
$('.car').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        // another rule,...
    });
});
```

Your fields all have the `required` rule.  If you simply toggle that rule alone, the other rules would only come into play when the field is filled out, otherwise, ignored.

---

**EDIT 2:**

If you are hiding and showing these fields, you may not need to worry about toggling any rules at all.  The plugin, by default, ignores all rules on any field that is hidden or contained within a hidden element.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that. But that seems maybe only slightly more efficient than individual depends. There are probably 30+ fields involved. The rules wouldnt just be "required". Some use remotes, and some have complex rules, etc. I was hoping there was more of a bulk enable/disable option using predefined rules.

Comment: @Ahhk, I took your code and exactly filled in your blanks.   However, if every rule set is unique, then how can you possibly set them generically with any method?  No, there is no "bulk" toggle switch.  Otherwise, you'll have to post a more relevant code example to show more precisely what you want.

Comment: I added examples of the rule arrays in the OC/OQ.

Answer (score 0):

@Sparkey:

Wow. I saw your $('.car').each.. code and was like "Holly Shot! That's it!" Then, sadly, I realized that it wouldn't work afterall. The problem there is that (for example) the car checkbox could be checked (fields shown), the fields partially filled in, then checkbox unchecked (fields hidden). They wouldnt be required because required rule was removed, but the now hidden fields would still have values that could fail the other (not required) rules.

While your class-based solution would have been MUCH better and cleaner, I think the only option here would be to add/remove all the rules via the arrays/each like:

```
function addrules(rulearr) {

  for (var field in rulearr) {

     $('#'+field).rules('add', rulearr[field]);

 }

}

function removerules(rulearr) {

  for (var field in rulearr) {

     $('#'+field).rules('remove');

  }

}
```

On Change....

```
if ($('#has_car').is(':checked') == true) {

  $('.car_fields').show();
  addrules(car_rules_array);

} else {

  removerules(car_rules_array);
  $('.car_fields').hide();

}
```

Do you concur?

Thanks for your responses/time!

Comment: Actually, instead of adding/removing the rules every time a checkbox is changed, couldn't I just add them as needed via a $('#TheForm').submit(function()? This should (in theory anyway) assign the rules right before validation is called. Right? :)

Comment: I would definitely not use a `.submit()` handler to add/remove rules.  You will have potential timing issues as the `.submit()` handler will definitely compete with the plugin.  Stick with your checkbox event handlers.  You should not post an answer as a follow-up response... you risk down-votes and the answer will get removed.  Thanks.

Comment: You never revealed any HTML so I missed that you are somehow hiding these fields.  The plugin WILL simply ignore hidden fields... so if you're showing and hiding them, you will not need to worry about adding or removing any rules. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh wow. I so didnt realize that it would ignore hidden fields. Guess I can just go back to static rules for all the fields. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome!  Since this is more of a follow-up question/discussion than an answer, I recommend that you delete it before a mod does.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Just make another div that contains the sub checkbox with hidden default. Show it when they are selected.

```
$('#car_check_box').on('click', function() {
  $('#car_sub_check_box').fadeToggle();
});
```